# Use variables within a function with INSERT INTO

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to use a variable within the function so i can grab systemstate from several clients and put them into a local table.
It looks like this but now i am stuck with making a part variable

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_test.sync_systemstate(table_name TEXT, dbname TEXT, port int, hostname TEXT, username TEXT, wachtwoord TEXT) returns integer as $$

    DECLARE
    sql varchar;

    BEGIN

    sql :='truncate schema_test.' || table_name || '' ;

    execute sql;

    INSERT INTO schema_test.[variable table name]
    SELECT timestamp, component_name, component_type, status, message ...;

    RETURN port;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The INSERT INTO schema_test.[variable] is not working, well at least i cant make it working. Any suggestions on how to achieve that behind the schem_test comes the variable table name??

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that the same way you did with the `truncate` statement. (note that using `format()` is a better way of creating dynamic SQL strings)

Comment: Well... been trying to figure it out but cant seem to make it work (or understand actually..)
Ill wait till the system administrator is back

Comment: Like ***always***, your version of Postgres, please. It's essential for the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea. You're creating a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html), just use the native functionality for that.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW schema_test
  AS SELECT timestamp, component_name, component_type, status, message;
```

Then simply run [`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html)`schema_test;` it will clear out the old results and insert the new results of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use dynamic sql while insering data?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema_test.sync_systemstate(table_name TEXT, dbname TEXT, port int, hostname TEXT, username TEXT, wachtwoord TEXT) returns integer as $$

    DECLARE
    sql varchar;

    BEGIN

    sql :='truncate schema_test.' || table_name || '' ;

    execute sql;
    sql: = 'Insert into schema_test.' || $1 || ' SELECT timestamp, component_name, component_type, status, message ...'

    execute sql;

    RETURN port;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please make your code safer by ident-quoting your table name (or, even better, use `format()`).